# how can I create two dynamic objects with overloaded constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, dynamic-arrays

Please look the code below, it's a simple subject but I don't know.

```
class trial{
public:
    trial(){
        y = -1;
    }
    trial(int x){
        y = x;
    }
public:
        int y;
};


int main() {
    trial *trialPtr = new trial();     // creates a dynamic object with empty constructor
    trial *trialPtr1 = new trial(1);   // creates a dynamic object with overloaded constructor
    trial *trialPtr2 = new trial[2];   // creates two dynamic objects with empty constructor
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, how can I create two dynamic objects with overloaded constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are problematic in C++98/03, because you can't generally initialize them entirely freely. C++11 fixes this through uniform initialization. Now you can say,

```
new trial[2] { 1, 1 };
```

Comment: Ah this is not working :(

test.cpp:22: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
</br>
test.cpp:22: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization in array new
test.cpp:22: error: no matching function for call to 'trial::trial(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'

Comment: @CihadTurhan: As I said, it's a C++11 feature. With GCC, add `-std=c++0x` to the command line (or `-std=c++11` in GCC 4.7+).

Answer (score 3):

[This is not possible with an built in array](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.5)

However consider using a std::vector

```
vector<trial> var(10, trail(4));
```

This has the added benefit that you don't need worry about memory management

Adding an ugly solution because OP apparently wants it. Set **FOO** to appropriate value before creating the array.  **Please read comments before downvoting**

```
int FOO = -1;

class trial{
public:
    trial(){
        y = FOO;
    }
    trial(int x){
        y = x;
    }
public:
        int y;
};

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FOO = 4;
    trial *trialPtr2 = new trial[2];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @parapura, thanks for quick answer. However, for my project it's not allowed to used any built-in dynamic/static arrays, I must do it by using pointers. Can't we find any solution?

Comment: Vectors are always a Good Thing, but the traditional vector  constructors are only good for either copying an existing range or for filling everything with the same value. C++11 also lets you initialize vectors from a brace-list, with arbitrary content: `std::vector<std::string> v { "mom", "jim", "ezekiel" };`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntactic way to do this in C++, as in this (incorrect) example:
trial *trialPtr2 = new trial2;
You must do a "for" loop if you wish to use an array:

```
trial *trialPtr2[] = new (*trial)[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    trialPtr2[i] = new trial(3);
}
```